# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Buffer' in node js with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, buffer

I get error Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'Buffer'

when i tried to add Buffer data using + operator in node js with ts !!

Code is something like:

```
let  encrypted = Buffer.concat([iv, ciphertext, cipher.final()]).toString('base64');
```

or

```
let plaintext = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()], 2);
```

> About Buffer Method
>
> (method) Buffer.concat(list: readonly Uint8Array[], totalLength?:
> number): Buffer
>
> It Returns a buffer which is the result of concatenating all the
> buffers in the list together.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says - you cannot use `+` with buffers. Saying that, you don't even show code that `+` with buffers. What are you trying to do and why do you want to use `+` despite not being possible?

Comment: `let plaintext = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(ciphertext), decipher.final()]);`

Remove the second argument in the `concat` function